# UICollectionView embed youtube video still plays in another view

Tags: view, ios6, youtube, embed, uicollectionview

I have a video playing in a UICollectionView cell, basically a UIWebView embed with a youtube link. When i click on another cell which goes to another view, the video is still playing in the background. Since I have so many cells, its really hard to keep track of the video playing. Also when you tap a cell with a UIWebVIew (embed youtube video) it doesn't really detect the didSelectItemAtIndexPath.

Any suggestions would be helpful thanks!

Comment: Question seems to conflate two different issues. Unclear what's being asked for. Do you want to stop the video when going to another view, or is the problem that you're not going to another view in the first place? Perhaps consider separating out the problems here, maybe even posing two different questions if there are two different issues.

Comment: I have a UICollectionView, 1. The CollectionView has a UIWebView in each cell with an embed youtube video inside. 2. When i play the video and click another cell that goes to another view the video is still playing in the background. 3. How am I going to deal with multiple cells which have embed Youtube Videos in a UIWebView? The user can click anyone of them.

Comment: Is there anyway to capture the youtube video's event when i press play?

Answer (score 0):

Two thoughts.

Checkout NSNotificationCenter, you can maybe create an event when you press play and then watch for it.
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNotificationCenter_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Another option is to not play the video in the collection view, but rather segue to another view that plays the video.  I'm not sure if this is too different from the functionality you want, but it seems simpler.